# References in perl: Error in perl code

Tags: perl, reference

Here is my code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -w
  my $name = "mark";
  my $nameRef = \$name;
  print "${$nameRef}\n";
  print "$nameRef\n";
  my $ref = $nameRef + 1;
  $$ref = "antony";
  print "$ref\n";
  print "$$ref\n";
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

```
mark
SCALAR(0x9556cf8)
Modification of a read-only value attempted at ./stringPerl.pl line 7.
```

How to remove the above error?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that causes the error is:

```
$$ref = "antony";
```

That tries to asign the value "antony" to the referenced variable by $ref, but the line:

```
my $ref = $nameRef + 1;
```

It's not a valid reference. Try to replace simply by:

```
my $ref = $nameRef;
```

So `$ref` is the same as `$nameRef`, which is a reference to `$name`.

If you want to change a value in an array via a reference, you may write this:

```
my @names = ("mark");
my $nameRef = \@names;

$nameRef->[1] = "antony";

print "$names[1]\n";
print "$nameRef->[1]\n";
```

Comment: but I want to store "antony" in the next address i.e., after the one stored in $nameRef. How to do that?

Comment: The next address? just define a $name2 variable, $ref2=\$name2, and do $$name2="antony". A reference (pointer) needs a referenced variable

Comment: I wanted to create an array of strings. By next address I mean address just after where "mark" is stored

Comment: `push @$nameRef, "anthony";` more likely to be what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

Perl string references are not C string pointers. You cannot take a reference and increment it to point somewhere else.

When you do `my $ref = $nameRef + 1;`, it actually takes the `SCALAR(0x9556cf8)` string and adds 1, making it a string, not a reference.

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: I want to store "antony" in the address next to that stored in $nameRef

Comment: Again, perl is not C. Don't use references as you would use C points. If you want to make an array of strings, they: `my @array = ['string1','string2'];`

Comment: @jcaron: That would make an array containing an arrayref, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JimDavis, oooops! Indeed, it should be `my @array = ('string1', 'string2');`